# Avia layout builder can't remove tabs from tab section

Tags: wordpress

Hi ive just recently started using wordpress to edit my webpages for my job. I'm just trying to remove a single tab from the tab section. Howerver there isn't a x icon on the tabs i want to remove. Even thought i can edit the tab section there is not an option for removing child tabs. Only solution i have found was to create a whole new tab section and to manually create and copy the info by hand to the new tabs. It has over 12 tabs so i want to be faster and more efficient.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zkcQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you found an answer by now. There is a delete button--in a unintuitive location.
[image]

I'm having trouble with these tabs since I can't figure out where or how to add content. I see the box but can't enter any text or links from the tabs. I'll make a standalone post to see if someone can help explain what I'm doing wrong.